# chrome: CORS prefly request: status 405

Tags: google-chrome, cors

I'm developing a ionic app and I need to make some CORS requests for dev purpose.
I use chrome v49 with -disable-web-security. I also use an .htcacces to allow OPTIONS request.
But i still get an error 405.

[Chrome header sum'up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRWlr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. We already tried that but it did not succeed either.

The problem was server side. We used symphony witch refuse everything with is rly strict policy. To solve this we used NelmioCorsBundle.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the chrome Extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon): * from chrome webstore , enable

> cross-origin resource sharing

from its option, then reload the page